# Reactjs -- parent, child - state handling architecture for each

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a reactjs website that will feature an array of items to populate a table.

The parent shell will pull down a list of available records into an array -- and using a child component I want to populate the table rows with this data.

I've started to create the child component - but the properties fed by the parent were not being processed until I placed the state handling near the render function.

I did have a constructor in the child component setting states but it didn't seen the way to go -- should I set the state in componetDidMount or componentWillMount (-- if a new child is made?)

The child component will have buttons -- save, generate, cancel -- that need to then alter the initial loaded states -

//rules
the parent can create/remove children - from an array -- 
the child needs to take the initial values given by the parent - but then act independent from it - so the child can take the initial properties and then with the buttons inside it - make its own calls. The application is already bound by this parent array and that's causing malfunctions.

-- child needs to be able to be able to cancel - e.g. revert back to its original state before saved -- so if its touched - isDirty is then true. 
-- an old child - isNew: false - pre-existing data - only shows a save button. Only the name is editable
-- a new child -- isNew: true -- will at first show a generate button (save hidden) -- the generate button will be hidden and save will be shown if the user manually starts to enter data into the name field. -- the generate/save buttons are disabled until the user has selected a region.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/frosty-vaughan-kdl1v
should look something like this -- once the initial array has made the children - the parent should then only be able to Add blank children or remove new/old chidren -- all other states should then happen on the child level only -- cause you may have 3 new children, 5 old -- started changing values - some got saved, some got cancelled - independent changes..

parent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Child from "./Child";
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          name: "apple",
          currentCode: "BJ3343",
          previousCode: " ",
          region: "opt2",
          isNew: false,
          isDirty: false
        },
        {
          name: "cherry",
          currentCode: "AS3433",
          previousCode: " ",
          region: "opt1",
          isNew: false,
          isDirty: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  addChild() {
    let blank = {
      name: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      code: "",
      region: "",
      isNew: true,
      isDirty: true
    };

    this.state.list.push(blank);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addChild()}>Add Child</button>
        <button>Remove Child</button>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td />
              <td>Region</td>
              <td>Code</td>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>save/generate</td>
              <td>cancel</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.list.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <Child
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  item={item}
                />
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

child

```
//import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Child extends Component {
  generateCode = index => {
    //does an api call -- and then on success alters the value of the code
    //Make an api call here and suppose api call return code 213
    const responseCode = 231;
    return responseCode;
  };

  saveCode = index => {
    //does an api call -- and then on success makes the child isDirty: false, isNew: false
  };

  cancel = index => {
    //reverts states for this child
  };

  render() {
    const index = this.props.index;
    const { name, region, currentCode, isNew, isDirty } = this.props.item;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="selection" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <select disabled={!isNew} type="input" name="region" value={region}>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
            <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
            <option value="opt3">opt3</option>
            <option value="opt4">opt4</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input disabled={!isNew} type="input" value={currentCode} />{" "}
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="input" name="name" value={name} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={() => this.generateCode(index)}>Generate</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.saveCode(index)}>Save</button>
        </td>

        <td>
          <button onClick={() => this.cancel(index)}>Cancel</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

//latest 30th Sep 2019
https://codesandbox.io/embed/elated-raman-twdqr

^ will add/remove children -- mock db array to delete for backend

//latest 1st oct 2019
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-hodgkin-iyj43  - latest version - more stable

Comment: Why do you even need a state in child? Deriving state from props is a bad idea as mentioned by react developers [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html).

Comment: the child then needs to be able to modify their own states -- there will be buttons in the child component to make api calls to toggle the data inline

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-hodgkin-iyj43  - latest version - more stable

Comment: @TheOldCounty, could you update your problem with the latest?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move state upwards to the parent and access it in the child from the parent as illustrated in the updated answer. More details can be found here [Lifting up state official reactJS documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Or you can use centralised state management libraries like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react).

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
//define your parent as well as child state here. 
state={
  parentState={...},
  childState={name: '', region: ''}
}

handleChange = (newValues) => {
  this.setState({childState: newValues});
  // fetch data here and update it to the state
  fetch(){}
}

componentDidMount(){
  //fetch side effects here like data fecthing and setting state isLoading false here using setState
}

render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading){
    return (
      <p>Loading</p>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.cart.map((item, key) =>
            <Child key={item.id}
                name=item.name
                region=item.region
                values: {this.state.childState}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
      }
    </div>
  );
}
}


class Parent extends React.Component {
render() {
  // directly access data using props instead of state
  // pass the updated value upwards to the parent via this.props.handleChange(newValue)(depends on your implementation)
  // Access new value in the child in next render by this.props.childState
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: {this.props.values.name}</p>
      <p>Region: {this.props.values.region}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: ah but no - because the children then need to be able to modify their own props -- so once the props from parent have come down -- its not just a read only thing. There will be buttons in the child that will make api calls and also modify the data inline

Comment: Check out the updated answer and let me know if it solves your query.

Comment: I think the application is already like that - and that's the problem --- all of the child aspects are handled in one massive array that gets copied -- its got to be more inline actions -- where the parent provides the initial states to the child -- but then the child can update its own states from there on in -- cause they want to be about to cancel (return old state) , save, generate - that kind of thing -- so there will be buttons in the child components to action these.

Comment: well - is there one to start creating it -- its a very complicated piece of code - I'm trying to refactor it - by breaking it up as a separate component. On the tin -- clicking a generate button would make a call and then get a new value for the child state.code -- if you check my reviewed first post

Comment: That was I am trying to say. When you want to modify the state of the parent(which is passed to a child as a prop) use the `handleChange()` function to modify the parent state. The updated state wil be received by a child in the form of porps. Child Component need not have its own state. Keep the state in parent only  Read the links I posted

Comment: that's already the problem though -- it needs to be child state handled -- it has to allow the user to cancel their changes -- so updating the parent will cause a malfunction

Comment: I cant help you furthur unless I see reproducible code codesandbox

Comment: well lets get one made -- where to start

Comment: I've made it - but not sure why the frameworks not working - https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-example-bz00n

Comment: Let me know if this is what you want. https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bas-4toms .. Generate will generate code number. Save will save it and cancel will return to previous code number

Comment: No it has to be child dependent -- as in the parent shell you should be able to add new children ---  so this why I got to break away from the modification of the array in the parent etc.. -- so once the child has been set by the parent --- any other interaction has to then be child dependent - so they don't affect each other...  -- there will be input fields in each child holding some of these values -- and after safe two become disabled... generate/save are similar - but that becomes invoked when you start entering a field manually

Comment: My efforts are getting wasted this way. Update your question with proper description and explaination. Post the WORKING CODE SANDBOX LINK into the question of what you are trying to achieve and what part of the code is not working only then I can answer.

Comment: Its a very complicated application -- but all these functions really need to be put into the child - so it will update them independently -- if the array was fixed from the parent - that's one thing -- but the user will have the chance to add and remove children you see -- Its a complicated application -- mocking it further will take some more time but I will try --

Comment: its something like this -- I will explain more in the main ticket - https://codesandbox.io/embed/frosty-vaughan-kdl1v

Comment: Wait i will give it a try and revert back to you

Comment: I am trying to update the version to get it closer to the codebase

Comment: After hours of effort. Full working demo @TheOldCounty. https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-noether-z9bj8 . Let me know if it works

Comment: no its not right -- cause the children have to control their own states after they have been invoked... it can't go back to modify the parent array - as each child - should be to be touched -- then cancelled eg.. reverted to their own state. - Also need to add/remove children from the latest code base.

Comment: --- so if the user touches the row -- and cancels - it reverts back to the state it was initially

Comment: -- generate button is shown only at first if its a new row

Comment: --- if its an existing row -- then the save button is shown

Comment: -- if the user starts to type in the name -- then the generate becomes a save button -- toggle hidden

Comment: -- region isn't selectable for new rows - bug

Comment: Brother you cannot ask someone to implement exact full code neither have you provided with all these details before, The purpose of SO is to give an overview or hints of how the code works and what are the good practices. Understand the code and try to improve it by yourself

Comment: Also you cannot say it is a bug as your description of question is too subjective and incomplete.

Comment: I'm just saying -- but I've mentioned all along that the props have to go into the children - and then be set as states -- and from then on in - be modified at the child level.

Comment: cause - the parent shell - can add new children - remove old children --- 20 rows of 5 new, 15 old -- some touched rows - cancel, save, generate -- can't manipulate the parent array as such to compensate for those user changes

Comment: CHild state is managed by the child itself if you look at it. After the user saves it then only it is reflected in the parent

Comment: yeah but also the cancel features too -- its like all inline -- save, generate, cancel -- adding children/removing -- it can't go back and modify the parent array state - otherwise it will have a ton of bugs

Comment: Implement cancel feature yourself . I guess it is easy now

Comment: I will continue to implement these features -- but it can't communicate back to the parent to keep the children decoupled after initialization.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200214/discussion-on-answer-by-uneet7-reactjs-parent-child-state-handling-archite).

Comment: @uneet7 any improvements on this codebase -- this is doing what I need -- codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-hodgkin-iyj43